# C++ pragma section & imports

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, memory-management, portable-executable

I was trying to allocate my code in two sections, the first was .code section and the other is .stub section. It works as follows:
1- Main function is put in .stub section 
2- test function is put in .code section
3- Main starts from (.stub) and calls testfunction() from(.code). Here is the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string>

/* Declare .code as a read/write/execute segment */
#pragma section(".code",execute, read, write)
#pragma comment(linker,"/SECTION:.code,ERW")

/* .code segment begin (all generated executable code below will go in .code segment ) */
#pragma code_seg(".code")

void testfunction() { printf("IAM now in .code\n"); }
/*=======================================================================*/
// .stub SECTION
#pragma section(".stub", execute, read, write)
#pragma code_seg(".stub")

void _tmain()
{
    cout<<"I am main from .stup section\n"; 
    testfunction();
    return ;
}
```

Without iostream,string and namespace std, everything is good. The problem starts when I try to #include and  immediately after stdafx.h

The following error comes :

```
Error   7   error C2193: 'void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'public: static std::_Generic_error_category std::_Error_objects<int>::_Generic_object''(void)' : already in a segment    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory0 627 1   
Error   6   error C2193: 'void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'public: static std::_Iostream_error_category std::_Error_objects<int>::_Iostream_object''(void)' : already in a segment  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory0 627 1   
Error   5   error C2193: 'void __cdecl `dynamic atexit destructor for 'public: static std::_System_error_category std::_Error_objects<int>::_System_object''(void)' : already in a segment  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\xmemory0 627 1   mal
```

Searching error C2193, I found that it pops up when a function is in many sections. Knowing this, I moved iostream,string and namespace std down to .stub section. Now,everything works. I deduced that including on line makes it included in all next section!

Now, My question is

1. How could I make the include in one section only? (Assuming that
   my deduction is right).
2. If so, why windows.h didn't make the same error?

I hope to find an answer as soon as possible.

Comment: This looks like the type of code that should *particularly* avoid `using namespace std;`  Is it at all possible to do `using std::string;using std::vector;//etc` instead?  Or is it required for some reason?

Comment: using namespace std or std:: is not the problem, the problem are the includes as I need them. This is a proof-of-concept code, but the real code heavily depends on strings

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve by having a writable code section?

Comment: I study malware analysis and trying to implement well-known technique for obfuscation

Comment: I would just use `VirtualAlloc` and friends.

Comment: Can u explain more ?